# Calling a C# method on a input type submit button

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I am having some trouble figuring out how to call a method I wrote in the .CS file that will update the user password in the database.

Here is my current form:

```
 <form method="post" action="#" runat="server" name="edit_password_form">
    <div id="edit_password_popup">
        <table width="390" align="center" padding="10">
            <tr>
                <td><span class="error_field">*</span>Password:<br>
                    <input type="password" name="password_1" id="password_1" size="19" maxlength="30" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
                </td>
                <td><span class="error_field">*</span>Confirm Password:<br>
                    <input type="password" name="password_2" id="password_2" size="19" maxlength="30" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
                </td>
            </tr>

             <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add Password" id="add_pass" alt="Add Password" border="0"></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="No Thanks" id="no_thanks" alt="No Thanks" border="0"></td>
             </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Should I maybe have the c# method in the .aspx file instead of the .aspx.cs?

I want the C# method to run when the add_pass button is clicked. Any ideas on how I can achieve that?

Comment: First off, change your action in the form element to an actual backend endpoint. Then in that endpoint's code-behind you can handle the data that was posted.

Comment: So have the action path be the aspx.cs file ?

Comment: No, the action path would be the .aspx file. That is, if you are not doing any URL rewriting.

Comment: Ok I see. Why would I want to redirect to another page? Wouldn't it be better if once they added the 2 passwords fields, they stay on the same page?

Comment: It depends on the business requirement, but often you would post back to the page you are currently on and then in the backend have your application redirect to its proper destination if everything worked appropriately (usually some sort of dashboard or admin landing page on a login).

Comment: ahh ok I see. Thank you for the info, the action tip helped alot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you are using ASP.NET Web Forms (since you have an actual ASPX file).

If that is the case, ASP.NET handles quite a bit of this for you and will actually perform a `POST` to itself, which allows its contents to be accessible in your code-behind.

You could consider replacing your existing `submit` button with an actual `<asp:Button>` that points to a specific method to hit in your code-behind when the form is posted :

```
<asp:Button ID="AddPassword" Text="Add Password" ... OnClick="AddPassword_Click"><asp:Button>
```

The `OnClick` event will handle mapping your Button being clicked to an event in your `aspx.cs` file that looks like :

```
protected void AddPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // This code will be executed when your AddPassword Button is clicked
}
```

If you replace your entire code with the related ASP.NET code, it would look something like the following section(s) :

**YourPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="YourPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="YourProject.YourPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Password Checking</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- This will post back to your YourPage.aspx.cs code-behind -->
<form id="form1" runat="server" name="edit_password_form">
<div id="edit_password_popup">
    <table width="390" align="center" padding="10">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="error_field">*</span>Password:<br />
                <!-- Replaced <input> elements with matching <asp:TextBox> controls -->
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password1" runat="server" TextMode="Password" size="19" maxlength="30" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td><span class="error_field">*</span>Confirm Password:<br>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Password2" runat="server" TextMode="Password" size="19" maxlength="30" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- Updated submit button to proper <asp:Button> -->
                <asp:Button ID="AddPassword" runat="server" Text="Add Password" OnClick="AddPassword_Click" alt="Add Password" border="0"><asp:Button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" value="No Thanks" id="no_thanks" alt="No Thanks" border="0" />
            </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**YourPage.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class YourPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // This will get called when your form is submitted
    protected void AddPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When your page is posted back, compare your passwords
        if(String.Equals(Password1.Text,Password2.Text))
        {
            // Your passwords are equal, do something here
        }
        else
        {
            // They aren't equal, do something else
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rion. This worked well and gave me some more inside knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

If you add the onclick event to your code, it should work to

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Password" id="add_pass" onclick="AddPassword_Click" alt="Add Password" border="0">
```

When your code runs on server side use `onserverclick=...`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the input type button, then you can use runat="server" and the onclick="MyMethod". For example:

```
< input type="submit" runat="server" value="Add Password" id="add_pass" alt="Add Password" onclick="Add_Pass_Click" on border="0" >
```

in your markup, and use the handler:

```
using MyClass.cs; 

protected void Add_Pass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyClass.DoSomeStuff(); //maybe, it's static
}
```

That is, if I understood your question.
Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/571190/howplustopluscodeplusinputplustypeplusbuttonpluscl ,